# When preparing a ristretto shot, should the brew time remain the same as a normale?

Tags: brewing-process, espresso

I have heard that a ristretto shot is in the realm of 1:1.1-1.5  bean to coffee yield ratio [here](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/a/2456). Is the brew time to remain the same? I have used about 25s as a rule of thumb for my espresso shots. If so, the flow of coffee from the machine is very slow, but if not the shot can be completed very quickly. I have tried both preparations and prefer keeping the shot time constant. Is this the prevailing wisdom?

Comment: I am not sure to understand the "coffee to bean" ratio? The link mentions "coffee to yield", which is different, if not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks I edited it to keep the link and my post consistent!

Comment: How do you think about rephrasing the question title? It seems the real question is "Is the brew time to remain the same?". I was answering when I noticed that, and scrapped my tentative (for now).

Comment: Very true. My question and title did not match. I've updated as well.

Answer (score 1):

The time could absolutely stay the same for both your ristretto and normale shots. But - for that to happen your grind is certainly going to have to change, and obviously your yield (since you are now pulling a smaller / ristretto shot).

An example:
If you pull a shot that's:

20g in | 25s | 20g out

And then you decide to pull a larger/normale shot, but you want to keep the time constant. Then you are basically forced to loosen your grind to a coarser grind size.
Then you could pull your normale at:

20g in | 25s | 30g out

Hopefully that answers your question!

Comment: I appreciate the analysis on how to keep the brew time constant, but my question really wanted to address if you should in the usual preparation. Saying that I could was a little unsatisfying as a definitive answer.

Comment: Ah I understand. Yes, the time should certainly be around the same exact length.